# Creating custom objects inherit NSObject class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsobject

Using different frameworks in my projects I have often faced with custom elements which created as class inherit from NSObject (correct me if something is wrong). What are the main rules of creating such UI elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSObject` is the very basic class in Cocoa. It is responsible for the most basic things that every class needs, like memory management. (Almost) all classes in Cocoa inherit from `NSObject` and you usually subclass `NSObject` if you want to implement a model class.

If you want to create your own GUI element, you should subclass `UIView` or `UIControl`. `UIView` will give you capabilities to do custom drawing, handling touch events and others. `UIControl` (which itself is a `UIView` subclass) adds functionality for control elements which the user can interact with, like `UITextField`, `UISlider` etc. This is what you should subclass if you plan to implement a custom control.

Comment: Not all classes inherit from `NSObject`. For instance, `NSProxy` is used for message-forwarding ("proxy") classes.

Answer (score 1):

Main purpose of using custom objects is to create model classes, which help in storing data which can be used through out the application.

For e.g. -

```
@interface ServerResponse
.....
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *responseString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *errorCodes;
.....
@end
```

In addition to this `NSObject` is root class in Objective C. Most classes inherit the feature of `NSObject` Classs.

Comment: `NSObject` is only *one* root class in Objective-C. Not all classes inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating UI elements you could inherit from `NSObject`, however I would strongly recommend to inherit from `UIView` or `UIControl`. Otherwise you will just be recreating functionality already given by `UIControl`.

Additionally if you simply want to add additional functionality to a existing UI element, you could extend (create a category) to add that functionality.